# Traffic services: useful or a waste of time?

Tags: seo, traffic

I found some services which offer to buy traffic.

```
buysitetraffic.com
revisitors.com
perfectraffic.com
```

Has anyone works with them?

Or maybe You have own experience with another services?

Is this idea useful or I waste time?

Comment: Well even Google Adwords is a paying for traffic... You want a service that requires people to click otherwise people being sent to your site regardless if they are clicking or not clicking then the chances are they are not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

These services almost certainly are a waste of time (and money)

The traffic these sites drive is generally very low (maybe not even human) and the odds of you converting these visitors into sales/leads/any other goal on your site, is very remote.

Google doesn't look at traffic volume when deciding ranking so this would have 0 impact on SEO too.